# Probability of Intersection

Tags: probability-theory

For events $A$ and $B$, probabilities $\mathsf P(A), \mathsf P(B), \mathsf P(A ∪ B)$ are given.

How do we calculate $\mathsf P(A^\complement ∩ B)$? I have tried using the properties $\mathsf P(A ∪ B) = \mathsf P(A) + \mathsf P(B) - \mathsf P(A ∩ B)$ and $\mathsf P(A^\complement) = 1 - \mathsf P(A)$, but to avail.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(B \cap A^C)= P(B)-P(A \cap B)$$